# File Uploading - Limit File Types in "File Upload" Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a question regarding file uploading, I need to limit file types, but I like to do it in the “File Upload” window, so the user can’t even see files that are not allowed for uploading, I like to do it in js or jquery.

I know it’s possible for example, uploadify plugin does this, but I don’t want to use it for a number of reasons.

Comment: This can't be done in Javascript, period. Your best option is to filter out invalid extensions prior to uploading, but no browser will let you mess with the file selection window for security purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link out.  It should give you about what you need.  It just uses straight javascript, I don't think there are any JQuery options for this yet.

http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4Q8H9E

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function TestFileType( fileName, fileTypes ) {
if (!fileName) return;

dots = fileName.split(".")
//get the part AFTER the LAST period.
fileType = "." + dots[dots.length-1];

return (fileTypes.join(".").indexOf(fileType) != -1) ?
alert('That file is OK!') : 
alert("Please only upload files that end in types: \n\n" + (fileTypes.join(" .")) + "\n\nPlease select a new file and try again.");
}
// -->
</script>
```

I've updated this answer with the actual code from the posted link.  As the poster notes this is not a "secure" solution to this problem.  As this is client side javascript the extension of the file can be changed easily with web development tools.  Always check uploaded files on the server side to prevent malicious files from being uploaded.

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge, we can do that as shown below, but still the dialogue contains all file types :

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

But, you can restrict the file upload of wrong type with Jquery/Javascript, i guess before sending the file to server by checking the extension.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do this from your HTML using the `input` tag?
Try this:

`<input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".pdf, .jpg, .png">`
This will allow you to upload files with .PDF, .JPG, .PNG extensions only.

This one worked for me, no need to JS